# Events in UserControl

Tags: events, user-controls, propertygrid

I am new to UserControls, and while developing my own control I found a problem with 
showing events of my control in the property grid at design time.
If I have some events in my control I want to see them in Property grid and if I double-click that I want to have a handler, in the same way Microsoft does for its controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should automatically appear if I'm not mistaken. Make sure you've built your project though, or changes won't propagate to open designers. And make sure it's a **`public`** event too. (Private/protected events rightfully shouldn't show up because they're not accessible.)

One thing you can do to make your user's design experience nicer is to do something like the following:

```
    [Description("This event is raised when the user presses the enter key while the control has focus."),
    Category("Key")]
    public event EventHandler EnterPressed;
```

The "description" bit puts a nice message in the description panel of the property window. The "category" bit puts it in a certain category (the default is Misc. at the end).

By the way, you haven't specified a language or environment, so the above may need to be modified if it's not C# in Visual Studio 2005+.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this pattern, to create a custom event in UserControls:

```
    #region MyEvent CUSTOM EVENT

    protected virtual void OnMyEvent(MyEventEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, e);
    }

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventEventArgs e);
    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    public class MyEventEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

    }

    #endregion MyEvent CUSTOM EVENT
```

This has the same naming convention of Microsoft events, you can fire OnMyEvent from inside your control, have custom EventArgs, handle MyEvent from other controls.

Answer (score 0):

You should be use Delegate at UserControl and raise it at Main page (aspx page) .If this way didn't work,you should be careful when register UserControlID.It need differ with other UserControl.Each UserControl need a ID.